# Are js functions defined in modules accessible outside that module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, module

I current have some code that looks like this:

```
 // when the document is ready
   execute myFunction();

  (function($){
      function myFunction()
       {
         // code 
       };
  })(jQuery);
```

The console is saying that myFunction is not defined...why?

Comment: Depends on the kind of module pattern that is used, and whether you export them. In your case, it obviously isn't.

Comment: *"The console is saying that myFunction is not defined...why?"* Because JavaScript has lexical scope. `myFunction` is defined inside another function and hence can't be accessed outside of that function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not accessible because you've put your function inside another self-invoking function, and the call to it is outside that.

Your comment states that you want the call to `myFunction()` to happen on load, which if your current code worked, would not be the case anyway. It would call the function before DOMReady.

To get the behaviour you want, place the function call within the SIF:

```
(function($){
    myFunction();

    function myFunction() {
        // code 
    };
})(jQuery);
```